# How to navigate items in a Listbox using Up and Down arrows

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a listbox in a form. The listbox is bound to 1 column.
The form records and the ListBox Records on [CustomerName] field are both sorted `A-Z`.
I want to be able to navigate the List Items using the `Up` and `Down` keys.
But I currenly see the listbox is looking for a ID macth instead. Is it possible to to select the records sequentially using the `Up` and `Down` Keys?

I have:

```vb
Private Sub Form_Current()
    Me.ListBox = Me.txtID.Value
Exit Sub
```

I also have:

```
Private Sub ListBox_AfterUpdate()
    Dim rs As Dao.Recordset
    Set rs = Me.RecosetClone
    rs.FindFirst "[ID] = ' " & Me.ListBox & " '"
    If.Not rs.NoMatch Then
        Me.Dirty = False
        Me.Bookmark = rs.Bookmark
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    End If

End Sub
```

My attemp is:

```vb
Private Sub Form_Current()
    Me.ListBox = Me.txtID
    Dim itemPosition As long
    With ListBox
        If .ItemsSelected.Count = 0 Then
            Exit Sub
            itemPosition = .ItemsSelected(0)
        If .itemPosition <> 0 Then
            .Selected(itemPostion -1) = True
        Else
            .Selected(itemPostion +1) = True
    End With
Exit Sub
```

Comment: This is a multi-select listbox? As far as I can tell, cannot select multiple records with arrow keys. What happens with your code - error message, wrong result, nothing?

Comment: @June7 The `Multi Select` property is set to None. The code runs but keeps jumping between items items instead of selecting them sequentially. There is No error message. In the fist attempt.

Comment: Why do you need code? When focus is on listbox, the up and down arrow keys naturally navigate lines.

Comment: @June7 I managed to sort it out by removing the `With` statement and using `Me.ListBox.Rowsource = "Select * FROM tbl1"` then ensuring that the listbox has 2 bound columns.

Comment: Your VBA code is invalid: your `ListBox_AfterUpdate` has two `End If` but only one `If`, and your `Sub Form_Current()` has two `If` but no `End If`.